# Why Flask Migrations does not detect a field's length change?

Tags: python, postgresql, alembic, flask-migrate

I have the following model, I want to change the length of name, when I do the migration it does not detect the changes

```
class Client(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = "client"
    client_id = db.Column(
        db.Integer,
        primary_key=True,
        autoincrement=True
    )
    name = db.Column(db.String(65))
    email = db.Column(db.String(255))
```

For example change to

`name = db.Column(db.String(100))`

`NFO  [alembic.env] No changes in schema detected.`

But when I change the name, if it detects the changes

```
INFO  [alembic.autogenerate.compare] Detected added column 'client.name_test'
INFO  [alembic.autogenerate.compare] Detected removed column 'client.name'
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

## Update - June 2020

Type comparison changed in Alembic 1.4, so field length changes should be more reliably identified. From the changelog:

> A major rework of the “type comparison” logic is in place which
>   changes the entire approach by which column datatypes are compared.
>   Types are now compared based on the DDL string generated by the
>   metadata type vs. the datatype reflected from the database. This means
>   we compare types based on what would actually render and additionally
>   if elements of the types change like string length, those changes are
>   detected as well. False positives like those generated between
>   SQLAlchemy Boolean and MySQL TINYINT should also be resolved. Thanks
>   very much to Paul Becotte for lots of hard work and patience on this
>   one.

The change log also cites [this issue](https://github.com/sqlalchemy/alembic/issues/605) and [this documentation](https://alembic.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/autogenerate.html#autogenerate-detects).

---

## Original Answer

**TL;DR**:

```py
context.configure(
    # ...
    compare_type = True
)
```

I've testing this on a string length change in PG backend and it does work, however as you can see below, the docs currently state that it should not. Here's the [relevant section of the docs](https://alembic.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/autogenerate.html#what-does-autogenerate-detect-and-what-does-it-not-detect):

> Autogenerate can **optionally detect**:
>
> - Change of column type. This will occur if you set the
>     EnvironmentContext.configure.compare_type parameter to True, or to a
>     custom callable function. The default implementation only detects
>     major type changes, such as between Numeric and String, and **does not
>     detect changes in arguments such as lengths**, precisions, or
>     enumeration members. The type comparison logic is extensible to work
>     around these limitations, see Comparing Types for details.

And the API Reference for [`compare_type`](https://alembic.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/api/runtime.html#alembic.runtime.environment.EnvironmentContext.configure.params.compare_type) states:

> Indicates type comparison behavior during an autogenerate operation.
>   Defaults to False which disables type comparison. Set to True to turn
>   on default type comparison, which has varied accuracy depending on
>   backend. See Comparing Types for an example as well as information on
>   other type comparison options.

Lastly, in the section titled, [Comparing Types](https://alembic.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/autogenerate.html#comparing-types), the following example is given for how to enable the type comparisons:

```py
context.configure(
    # ...
    compare_type = True
)
```

You'll find the `context.configure()` call in the `env.py` script that is automatically generated by alembic nested inside the connect context:

```py
with connectable.connect() as connection:
    context.configure(
        connection=connection, target_metadata=target_metadata
    )
```

... and just add the `compare_type` param in there.

In the same section, they go on to say:

> Note The default type comparison logic (which is end-user extensible)
>   currently works for major changes in type only, such as between
>   Numeric and String. The logic will not detect changes such as:
>
> - changes between types that have the same “type affinity”, such as
>     between VARCHAR and TEXT, or FLOAT and NUMERIC
> - changes between the arguments within the type, **such as the lengths of
>     strings**, precision values for numerics, the elements inside of an
>     enumeration.
>
> Detection of these kinds of parameters is a long term project on the SQLAlchemy side.

So it's interesting to see it mentioned a couple of times in the docs that this should not work. As mentioned earlier, I have tested this on postgres and can confirm that setting `compare_type=True` does generate a revision for the length of the column, so perhaps the docs are lagging a little behind on this, or the maintainers aren't ready to declare it as a feature yet.

I've also tested on MySQL and can confirm that string length changes are also picked up if `compare_type=True`.

Comment: Super answer here!

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

I am assuming you are using the Flask-Migrate package for migrations.
By default, Alembic doesn't recognize the change on the existing column attribute changes.

You should add
`compare_type=True` when you create the `Migrate` class

`migrate = Migrate(app, db, compare_type=True)`

Now again you try to `flask db migrate` to generate new alembic migration .py file for newly changes on existing column

Answer (score 0):

Short answer for SuperShoot's answer above:

Open `migrations/env.py`

Find

```
    with connectable.connect() as connection:
    context.configure(
         ...
    )
```

Add `compare_type=True,` inside.

Run again.